# How to Vertical align and horizontal align div?

Tags: html, css

I have a video. And I have a group of text that I want to center vertically and horizontally on top of the video like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/k05U0.jpg

Also I don't want to use the transform: translate method because **I want to support IE8.**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OjKxxj

```
<section class="container">

  <!-- Video -->
  <video src="https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/000/108/original/Hiking.mp4"></video>


  <!-- Need to center this div -->
  <div class="center-group">
    <h1>Need to center this</h1>
    <h2>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</h2>
    <a>Button</a>      
  </div>


</section>

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body, .container {
  height: 100%;
}

video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;  
  object-fit: cover; 
}

.center-group {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;      
  top: 0;
  background: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use display:

- flex *(nowdays browsers)*

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body,
.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;/* update*/
  align-items: center;/* update*/
  justify-content: center;/* update*/
}

video {
  position: absolute;/* update*/
  top: 0;/* update*/
  left: 0;/* update*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.center-group {
  position: relative;/* update*/
  width: 500px;
  /*top: 0;  update not needed */
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">

  <!-- Video -->
  <video autoplay src="https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/000/108/original/Hiking.mp4"></video>


  <!-- Need to center this div -->
  <div class="center-group">
    <h1>Need to center this</h1>
    <h2>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</h2>
    <a>Button</a>
  </div>


</section>
```

- table/table-cell *(nowdays and older browsers )*

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  /*update*/
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: table-row;
}

.container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.center-group {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  /* end update*/
  width: 500px;
  background: orange;
}

video {
  /*update*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* end update*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">

  <!-- Video -->
  <video autoplay src="https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/000/108/original/Hiking.mp4"></video>


  <!-- Need to center this div -->
  <div class="center-group">
    <h1>Need to center this</h1>
    <h2>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</h2>
    <a>Button</a>
  </div>


</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:absolute` *top* and *left* for your center-group, Update your codepen.

```
.center-group {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  top: 30%;
  left:40%;
  background: orange;
}
```

Check this: https://codepen.io/bhansa/pen/oeKGQL

Answer (score 0):

**You need to add one more parent div and css to make it vertically and horizontally center**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body, .container {
  height: 100%;
}

video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;  
  object-fit: cover; 
}

.center-group {
/*   position: absolute; */
  width: 500px;      
/*   top: 0;
  left:0; */
  background: orange;
}
.center-group-container{
    position: absolute;     
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
/*   background:red; */
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">

  <!-- Video -->
  <video autoplay src="https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/000/108/original/Hiking.mp4"></video>
  
  
  <!-- Need to center this div -->
  <div class="center-group-container">
  <div class="center-group">
    <h1>Need to center this</h1>
    <h2>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</h2>
    <a>Button</a>      
    </div></div>
</section>
```

**You need to add one parent div name .center-group-container**

> Changes in html css are as follows:
>   **HTML**

```
      <!-- Need to center this div -->
  <div class="center-group-container">
  <div class="center-group">
    <h1>Need to center this</h1>
    <h2>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</h2>
    <a>Button</a>      
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.center-group {
/*   position: absolute; */
  width: 500px;      
/*   top: 0;
  left:0; */
  background: orange;
}
.center-group-container{
    position: absolute;     
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
/*   background:red; */
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```